# Access JSON data with string path?

Tags: javascript

```
var give = 'i.want.it';

var obj = {
    i: {
        want: {
            it: 'Oh I know you do...'
        }
    }
};

console.log(obj[give]); // 'Oh I know you do...'
```

Can I somehow get the object string using a path String of some sort? I'm trying to store a relationship in a database where the field it can't be in it's own document.

Comment: Take a look to this: http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ Very interesting!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use **[`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** method

```js
var give = 'i.want.it';

var obj = {
  i: {
    want: {
      it: 'Oh I know you do...'
    }
  }
};


var res = give.split('.').reduce(function(o, k) {
  return o && o[k];
}, obj);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: How we can do it in somw string like `’i.want.it bro’ I mean it contains another texts but we only use . part of it do you know how to do it

Comment: How would you do it if the object contains arrays?

Comment: @Dolan `data.0.prop`

Answer (score 2):

make it

```js
var obj = {
    i: {
        want: {
            it: 'Oh I know you do...'
        }
    }
};
//var result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)); //cloning the existing obj
var result = obj; //cloning the existing obj
var give = 'i.want.it';

//now split the give and iterate through keys
give.split(".").forEach(function(key){
  result = result[key];
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hmm pretty nifty! I'll try it out and get back.

Comment: Cloning the object is not necessary. It would be enough to assign obj to another reference (var result = obj;).

Answer (score 2):

This will work :

```
var give = 'i.want.it';

var obj = {
  i: {
    want: {
      it: 'Oh I know you do...'
    }
  }
};

console.log( eval("obj."+give));
```

[Live DEMO JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4scq4q7u/)

This is a really easy way to do it, but not safe, i don't advise you to use it for professional use. Use previous answer they looks good.

Comment: This solution works with complicated JSON objects too which contains arrays. Upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use eval()

var obj = {"a": { "b": { "c": 3}}};
writeln(eval('obj.a.b.c') + 2);

This will output 5.

JavaScript is weakly typed and thus it's evaluation function executes a statement as well as evaluating an expression.