# Can i use string as pointer in object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a object. lets say

> var obj = {"a":{"b":{"c":3}}}

I can get the value of c as

> var value = obj.a.b.c;

So lets assume i have a string

> var str = 'a.b.c';

Can i use this string to get the value of "c" in Object obj.

Comment: what will happen if object is  `{"a.1":{"b.1":{"c.1":3}}}`?

Comment: there is no such thing in my case. its simple key.

Comment: @Rishi : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37611143/access-json-data-with-string-path

Comment: @PranavCBalan Thanx man!

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You say "let's assume I have a string"--where did this string come from? JS is a functional languages. Instead of inventing your own mini-syntax to address nested properties, which you then have to parse and execute, just use built-in JS machinery. So instead of a string like `a.b.c`, define an accessor such as `function get(o, p) { return o && o[p]; }`, and then write `var str = o => get(get(get(o, 'a'), 'b', 'c')));`.